# MySQL Workbench Unable to Retrieve Disk Space in Data Dir, Server Stopped

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I had mySQL workbench working fine a few weeks ago.  Now, any time I log in, I get `no connection`.  Upon inspecting `Sever Status`, it is showing `Stopped`.  Also, under the `Server Directories`, it says `Unable to Retrieve` next to Disk Space in Data Dir.

I also noticed that the configuration file was wrong, or outdated?  The `Configuration File` originally read:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

But I looked and there was no MySQL Server 5.5 file in my directory.  I do have a MySQL Server 8.0 folder, so I changed the Configuration File to:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
```

However, this fails to solve the problem.  I've also attempted to run `Services` from the Start Menu, right click on `MYSQL80`, and choose `start` - and it says the service has `Started then stopped`.

I'm not even sure this missing or mis-directed file is the issue, or whether it's the `Unable to Retrieve Disk` error (or both are causing the server to fail).  I recently changed my login password for my computer - but I doubt that is related to the login credentials for MySQL, right?  (I see MYSQL80 properties has password for 'log on' option, but I have no idea what this password even is, or how to change it).

I've also read about this problem online and cannot seem to find an answer that solves the issue.  I've tried running MySQL Workbench as an admin too, and that doesn't work either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Is there a way to get the server up and running again without a bunch of complicated command line?  I appear to have mysqld.exe in the `bin` file in MySQL 8.0

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Maybe change back the inifile before you start the service.

Comment: Golez, thanks for the reply.  I've made some progress and seem to have isolated the problem .  It seems to be a permissions issue.  I made a new post here:                                                                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715233/os-errno-13-permission-denied-mysql-server

Answer (score 2):

In MySql Workbench ***`Server -> Startup/ShutDown -> Start Server`***.
This Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When the my.ini file is messed up I think the best solution is a total uninstall/delete and manual install. Before you do any of the following make sure you go to your current data dir and save your database folders. Then dlete all of your current MySQL related directories and uninstall MySQL and MySQL workbench.

I had this problem when I installed MySQL 8.0.15 with the community installer. The my.ini file that came with the installer did not work correctly after it had been edited. I did a full manual install by downloading that zip folder. I was able to create my own my.ini file containing only the parameters that I was concerned about and it worked.

1. download zip file from MySQL website
2. unpack the folder into C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0
3. within the MySQL8.0 folder that you unpacked the zip folder into, create a text file and save it as my.ini
4. include the parameters in that my.ini file that you are concerned about. so something like this(just ensure that there is already a folder created for the datadir or else initialization won't work):

   ```
   [mysqld]
   basedire=C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0
   datadir=D:\MySQL\Data
   ....continue with whatever parameters you want to include
   ```
5. initialize the data directory by running these two commands in the command prompt:

   ```
   cd C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0\bin
   mysqld --default-file=C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0\my.ini --initialize
   ```
6. install the MySQL server as a service by running these two commands:

   ```
   cd C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0\bin
   mysqld --install --default-file=C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0\my.ini
   ```
7. finally, start the server for the first time by running these two commands:

   ```
   cd C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL8.0\bin
   mysqld --console
   ```