# OS errno 13 - Permission Denied MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having issues with MySQL workbench - I can't seem to start the server.  In the command line, I navigate to:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\
```

And then run `mysqld --initialize`

I get the following error:

```
    mysqld: Can't create directory 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2018-12-10T23:18:55.211840Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) initializing of server in progress as process 36568
2018-12-10T23:18:55.227851Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-12-10T23:18:55.230796Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?  I already checked the permissions on the MySQL Server 8.0 folder, and have set all the permissions to Allow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 - Stopped MySQL. Now it won't start (error 13, permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370142/ubuntu-20-04-stopped-mysql-now-it-wont-start-error-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give writing permissions to the following folders:

**PATH/DATA/**

**PATH/QUERIES/**

**PATH/LOG/**

for the user who starts the MySQL windows service, which if not a special one you created and use for such purpose, is **NETWORK SERVICE**.